# Alternating background colors on ListView.builder

Tags: dart, flutter, widget

I have a `ListView.builder` generating `ListTile`s from a List. I would like to achieve an alternating color like you would a typical list.

Is there a Flutter official way to do this? Or I'm stuck with doing something like

```
ListView.builder(
...
  itemBuilder: (...) {
    return ListTile
      ..
      title: Container(
        decoration: BoxDecoration(color: Colors.grey),
          child: Column(children: <Widget>[
            Text("What should've been the title property"),
            Text("and its trailing"),
          ],),
      ),
```

or something to that effect?

Comment: you have an `index` passed to `itemBuilder` - just use it

Comment: @pskink I'd like to get an answer on *how to style* it, specifically, thank you. I can use the index to determine whether it's odd or even.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Got it.

Instead of using `ListTile` I can use a `Card` to have the *color* property accessible. Then with @pskink's suggestion, I can use the index to determine whether it's odd or even.

Comment: You can also just wrap the `ListTile` in `Container` and set its color.

Answer (score 28):

You can use the `index` provided to the item builder to set the color, and if you want to use a `ListTile` you can easily give it a background color by wrapping it in a `Container`:

```
ListView.builder(
  itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
    return Container(
      color: (index % 2 == 0) ? Colors.red : Colors.green,
      child: ListTile(
        title: ...
      ),
    );
  },
)
```

Comment: How can I add more colors .I have 10 lists and i want to add 10 different colors how can i achieve this

Comment: Try changing the logic to `index % 10` and use a `switch` statement.

Comment: Small note, but you can use `index.isEven`.

Answer (score 2):

The way I did it is by setting up my list then creating a method where the return type is Color and the parameter passed in is the index.

```
Color selectedColour(int position) {
  Color c;
  if (position % 3 == 0) c = Colours.cTLightBlue;
  if (position % 3 == 1) c = Colours.cTMidBlue;
  if (position % 3 == 2) c = Colours.cTDarkBlue;
  return c;
}
```

In the Color named parameter call selectedColour and you'll have colours alternate the way you'd want.